# How to inject the driverClassLoader property in spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have the following partial spring context xml file:

```
<bean name="template" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean name="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassLoader" value="" /> <!-- THIS PROPERTY -->
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3061/my_database" />
  <property name="username" value="username" />
  <property name="password" value="password" />
  <property name="initialSize" value="8" />
</bean>
```

How do I inject the **driverClassLoader** property? (I'm using some custom plug-in architecture but not the spring dm server so have to provide a classloader to find the mysql driver)

Comment: Here is a link to the driverClassLoader setter method where I have to provide a ClassLoader:
http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html#setDriverClassLoader%28java.lang.ClassLoader%29

Comment: Show how would you obtain that classloader without Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this apache dbcp classloader bug was just fixed in march 2011. 
It may fix your root issue so you don't need to inject the classloader...

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DBCP-333

without this bug fix I don't think the driverClassloader setter was working....

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. Look at section 3.7.2.1 in the [Spring 2.0 reference guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators).